# Radio button floats somewhere I don't want it

Tags: javascript, jquery, slide

My first HTML file was really messy, so I decided today to clean up the code.

Everything works fine except the radio buttons which are positioned inside a 'DIV` tag. This makes me really mad, because there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code.

HTML

```
<div class="sidebar border">    
    <div class="poll">
     <form> 
      <fieldset>

       <h3>Do you like peanuts ?</h3>

       <input type="radio">

       <label>yes</label>

       <input type="radio">

       <label>no</label>

      </fieldset>   
     </form>
    </div>      
</div>
```

CSS

```
#sidebar {      
        width: 13.1em; height: 34.6em;
        background-color: rgba(22, 43, 58, 0.9);
        float: left;
        margin-left: 0.6em;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        border: 1px solid rgba(10, 25, 36, 0.5);
        position: absolute;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0, 0.4)}


.poll {     
        height: 18em;
        font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
        font-size: 0.7em;
        border-radius: 20px;
        margin-top: 1em;}


.poll h3 {  text-align:center;}


.poll fieldset{ 
        color: #e3f1ff; 
        width: 15em; height: 10em; 
        border-radius: 20px;
        display: block;
        margin-left: 0.9em;
        background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.1);
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        border: 1px solid rgba(10, 25, 36, 0.7);}

.poll a     { color: white; }

.poll label, li { 
          display: block;
          padding: 5px;
          font-size: 0.9em;
          color: #e3f1fa;}
```

Thank you for your time !

ps. I know absolute positioning doesn't work with float.

[image: the error]

Answer (score 1):

try `display:inline-block` instead of `display:block` on the labels. then the labels are behind the radios. after that wrap every input with its label with another element like a div.

Comment: sorry man but this doesn't work for me, i've tried everything to get it display inside the fieldset.

Answer (score 0):

set the label display as `inline-block` and use a `<br>` to send the second radio button to the next line. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f7xdnux4/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="sidebar border">

<div class="poll">
<form>  
<fieldset>
    <h3>Do you like peanuts ?</h3>
<input type="radio" name="likePeanuts">
<label>yes</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="likePeanuts">
<label>no</label>
</fieldset> 
</form>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#sidebar {      width: 13.1em; height: 34.6em;
        background-color: rgba(22, 43, 58, 0.9);
        float: left;
        margin-left: 0.6em;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        border: 1px solid rgba(10, 25, 36, 0.5);
        position: absolute;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0, 0.4)}


.poll {     height: 18em;
        font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
        font-size: 0.7em;
        border-radius: 20px;
        margin-top: 1em;}


.poll h3 {  text-align:center;}


.poll fieldset{ color: #e3f1ff; 
        width: 15em; height: 10em; 
        border-radius: 20px;
        display: block;
        margin-left: 0.9em;
        background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.1);
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        border: 1px solid rgba(10, 25, 36, 0.7);}

.poll a     { color: white; }

.poll label, li { display: inline-block;
          padding: 5px;
          font-size: 0.9em;
          color: #e3f1fa;}
```

also give the credit to **@Chris**

**don't forget to set a name for your radio buttons**

Comment: thanks for the answer but this doesn't work for me, weird enough.

Comment: how come? have you checked the demo? is it not what you want?

Comment: i have checked the  DEMO and that is exactly what i want, but it doesn't work for me, i have another example of my previous HTML and it works in that one, but not in this one, it's driving me nuts !

Comment: i have added an image to the question, so you can see what it does

Comment: I'm sure the problem is not in the code that you're showing us, dig a little deeper, there must be something else making this not to work

Answer (score 0):

Before you write some HTML or CSS code (like I do) make
sure that you got this in your CSS file!

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0; /* if you want */
  resize: none;
}
```

that way you can avoid shitty browser fails or issues.

**IMPORTANT**

UL, LI, BODY and DIV Tags will be a little bit different. They lose
their default margin, padding. So give a try and if you aren't happy with this you can easily romeve it.

PS: Avoid working with floats if you can just remind.

Comment: this actually helped with another error haha, but unfortunately not with the radio buttons ! thank you !

Comment: no problem but if you want to get the radio stick together you should use `display: inline-block;` instead of `display: block;`

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code several times to figure out the error you are claiming about but I don't get it, but reading your code as is, I leave you the corrections I made:

```
<style>
#sidebar {      width: 13.1em; height: 34.6em;
    background-color: rgba(22, 43, 58, 0.9);
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0.6em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(10, 25, 36, 0.5);
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0, 0.4)}


.poll {     height: 18em;
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-top: 1em;}


.poll h3 {  text-align:center;}


.poll fieldset{ color: #e3f1ff; 
    width: 15em; height: 10em; 
    border-radius: 20px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 0.9em;
    background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    border: 1px solid rgba(10, 25, 36, 0.7);}

 .poll a     { color: white; }

.poll label, li { display: block;
      padding: 5px;
      font-size: 0.9em;
      color: #e3f1fa;}
      </style>     
 <div class="sidebar border">

<div class="poll">
<form>  
<fieldset>
    <h3>Do you like peanuts ?</h3>
<input type="radio"/>yes<br/>
<input type="radio"/>no<br />
</fieldset> 
</form>
</div>      

</div>
```

Comment: everything else stays in that place like a string of text, just not checkbuttons or radio buttons...